# Cannot see remote branches in Intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I recently got back to work on a project, and would like to merge my changes back into master.  The issue is that I cannot see any of the remote branches in the Intellij IDEA.  I've tried using Fetch and Pull, but have had no luck.

I'm not sure if this is relevant, but when I initially cloned the project, it was from this specific branch as opposed to master:

```
git clone -b <BRANCH NAME HERE> --single-branch <SSH PROVIDED BY GIT>
```

Edit: Though I've accepted an answer, I just wanted to mention that this also occurs when I clone from the master branch, switch to the branch that I should be on (which, incidentally, uses Gradle instead of Maven), and then create the project with the Gradle build file as an existing source (File -> New -> Project from existing source).  Obviously I did something wrong when I build the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

1. Add your remote as a new remote repository to Intellij
2. run `git fetch` again.

To add a remote repository `VCS` -> `Git` -> `Remotes...`

Here is how it looks like:
[image]